# How to create generic method for methods that have the same structure?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, design-patterns

I have the following method in `CommentsService` class:

```
async def background_job_auto_approve(self):
    while True:
        new = get_comments_by_status(CommentStatus.NEW.value)
        pending = get_comments_by_status(CommentStatus.PENDING.value)
        all = new + pending
        for comment in all:
            if check_it_auto_approve(item=comment):
                await self.auto_approve(comment_id=comment['comment_id'],
                                        alert_id=comment['alert_id'])
                yield comment
        await asyncio.sleep(self.check_expire_seconds)
```

But I have exactly the same method in my `AlertsService`:

```
async def background_job_auto_approve(self):
    while True:
        new = get_alerts_by_status(AlertStatus.NEW.value)
        pending = get_alerts_by_status(AlertStatus.PENDING.value)
        all = new + pending
        for alert in all:
            if check_it_auto_approve(item=alert):
                await self.auto_approve(alert_id=alert['alert_id'])
                yield alert
        await asyncio.sleep(self.check_expire_seconds)
```

How to avoid code duplication? I have the same problem for other methods in those classes.

Comment: How much of this is going on?  Just these 2 instances?  10?  You could refactor to pass in functions and prepared **operator.itemgetter** and the like that the code would then act on ex: **StatusSource.NEW.value**.   But you would make this code less epxpressive in terms of variable names and have to add extra code to call it.  At 2 duplications, not at all worth it.  At 5-6 maybe, 10+ certainly.

Comment: @JLPeyret Yes, I have 10+ duplications. Maybe, it will be good to have a decorator for each pair of the duplicate? Or create some abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to come up with a truly generic way to do this without the rest of the code base / context of it's purpose. However, if you can solidify the pattern you seem to be using (which is `[objectname]Status`, `[objectname]_id`, `get_[objectname]s_by_status`), this will work fine. I'd recommend adding an additional class for methods such as `auto_approve`

```
class AutoApprovalLoop(object):
    def __init__(self, method_ptr=None, cls_ptr=None, approval_key=None):
        self.method_ptr = method_ptr     # one of get_comments_by_status or get_alerts_by_status
        self.cls_ptr = cls_ptr           # one of AlertStatus or CommentStatus
        self.approval_key = approval_key # one of 'comment_id' or 'alert_id'

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            new = self.method_ptr(self.cls_ptr.NEW.value)
            pending = self.method_ptr(self.cls_ptr.PENDING.value) 
            all = new + pending
            for item in all:
                if check_it_auto_approve(item=item)
                await self.auto_approve(**{self.approval_key: item[self.approval_key]})
                yield item
            await asyncio.sleep(self.check_expire_seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of warning.  I am not on Python 3 and I am not entirely sure how the asyncio and async keywords behave when you forward calls to another function.

First thing first:  pass in as variables anything that is different between your first and second function.  That is:  which function returns your awaiting-approvals, and their status criteria object.

Then, use prepared operator.itemgetter to generically retrieve the keys from each obj.  If itemgetter has several fields to look up it returns a tuple, otherwise a scalar - that's what the `isinstance(tu, tuple)` tries to normalize.  Use `*tu` to unpack that back for the **auto_approve** call.

Call *check_it_auto_approve* and *self.auto_approve* with positionals, using

```
async def generic_background_job_auto_approve(self, get_obj_by_status, ObjStatus, myitemgetter):
    while True:
        new = get_obj_by_status(ObjStatus.NEW.value)
        pending = get_obj_by_status(ObjStatus.PENDING.value)
        all = new + pending
        for obj in all:
            #call with positional if possible.
            if check_it_auto_approve(obj):
                tu = myitemgetter(obj)
                #itemgetters return a tuple if multiple keys, a scalar if only one
                tu = tu if isinstance(tu, tuple) else (tu,)
                #assuming your auto_approve does ok with positional variables, doesn't need named ones
                await self.auto_approve(*tu)
                yield obj
        await asyncio.sleep(self.check_expire_seconds)
```

ok, now you are ready to call your generic code

```
import operator
async def call_for_comment(self):
    return self.generic_background_job_auto_approve(
        get_obj_by_status=get_comments_by_status
        ,ObjStatus=CommentStatus
        ,myitemgetter=operator.itemgetter('comment_id','alert_id')
        )

async def call_for_alert(self):
    return self.generic_background_job_auto_approve(
        get_obj_by_status=get_alerts_by_status
        ,ObjStatus=AlertStatus
        ,myitemgetter=operator.itemgetter('alert_id')
        )
```

If you needed to call with named parameters, you could pass in a function that return a dict of the required variables and **mydict to call instead.